# Bootstrap 3 form-control class on text input with custom padding hides text in IE and FF

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Seems to work fine in Opera and Chrome but the same code in FF and IE11 hides the text, which is no fun at all. I don't have a Mac so I don't know what it's like in Safari.

[Here is a plunker demonstrating the issue.](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpff3wsvsDNj5aluehlE?p=preview)

I've tried adding `line-height` and `overflow:visible`but neither seem to have much effect.

**css:**

```
#userResponse {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 1em 0.25em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input class="form-control" id="userResponse" type="text">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: By "text" you mean the input field? Because there is "text" in the HTML sample.

Comment: `.form-control` has a fixed height, that's why your text doesn't appear.

Comment: @KevinVoorn mean when I type something into the input field it is not visible in IE and FF. I know that it is actually being input but the padding or the fixed height makes it invisible.Just wondering if there is a good work around for this.

Comment: agreed. You are using em for text size and padding and px for height of the input. If your default font-size is 14px, thats 28px for font (at 2em) and 14px padding top and bottom. With the fixed height and a little math, its obvious this won't fit in.

Comment: It's even a padding top and bottom of 28px as the 1em reverts to the font-size of the element which is 28px (by the 2em of 14px). I guess Firefox and IE simply have different rules from Chrome on how to fail, not sure if the spec has anything on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap also has classes for input tags to increase the height of text fields, try with `input-lg`, hope it meets your requirement

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
```

remember to put all `form-control` inside `form-group`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
</div>
```

for more http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

Answer (score 0):

Luzan's solution is probably the best approach. However, to keep the the spacing similar to how it appears in chrome with the padding I gave it a new fixed height of 58px and removed the padding entirely. This seems to give consistent results across all four browsers.

[Updated Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpff3wsvsDNj5aluehlE?p=preview)

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input class="form-control" id="userResponse" type="text" value='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz'>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control custom" type="text" value='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz'>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**css:**

/* Styles go here */

```
#userResponse {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 1em 0.25em;
    text-align: center;
}

.custom {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2em;
  height:58px;
}
```